# meteor local dev environment vs production environment

Tags: linux, nginx, meteor, localhost, production-environment

I'm working on a meteor app which runs on UBUNTU Linux EC2, node, and nginx.  However I develop on Mac OS 10.9.5.

If my production app is running on Linux, should I attempt to be developing on an OS as close as possible to my production app in order to minimize corner case errors?

In other words, is it best to replicate server environment in dev? or do the dev tools for the given job speed up the workflow enough that it's cost effective to work in a different OS, and any errors occurred are really not a huge cost factor, generally speaking for Meteor dev and common Linux server environments?

Answer (score 1):

Usually you cant beat server performance with laptop or desktop.
So common nix (unix/linux, bsd/osx) environment is great.
Even Windows is used by web-developers (not great, but OK).

Most important part here is not hardware and OS but LEMP/LAMP software versions. So try to keep em equal with server. And proper setup all error logs :)

Answer (score 1):

We're working with OSX machines for development and deploy to Linux servers and we haven't run into any issues unless there are binary packages involved and we have a fairly large Meteor codebase.
We do bundle the app on the server though.

Also I'm currently developing a Meteor package with a lot of binary dependencies where there would be significant overhead associated with maintaining cross platform compatibility but using the synced folder feature (with NFS) of Vagrant works pretty good.